# How can I get the complete list of sites with the Adsense Management API v2?

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

I have been using the adsense management api v2 and I now notice that the sites listed aren't complete. The report on the adsense dasboard shows all the domain names/sites but I cannot figure out why all of the sites are being listed.

I've already checked with all the ad client IDs, and there are no child accounts, etc.
The ad units are created on the same parent account as well